# Why not able to use dataType = "xml" in post() call?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a **post()** call that reads down an xml file and since this is a lproper xml file it seems I should be able, and I should, make the dataType="xml".  But this breaks the call.  It works fine though if I make dataType="text". Does anyone see the problem?

```
$.post('loadPage.php', { siteName : siteName},function(xml) {
Status2$.html(xml);
var bdystyle = $(xml).find("bodyStyle")[0].textContent;
var canvasstyle = $(xml).find("canvasStyle")[0].textContent;
},
"text");
```

**The php is:**

```
<?php
    $siteName       = $_POST['siteName'];
    $fileName = "{$siteName}_sav.xml";
    $fileSize = filesize($fileName);
    $filePath =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" . $fileName;
    $site_fp = fopen( $filePath, 'r');
    $xml = fread($site_fp, $fileSize);
    echo $xml;
?>
```

And the xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
   <bodyStyle>background-image: none; background-color: rgb(255, 254, 253); cursor: auto;</bodyStyle>
   <canvasStyle>background-image: none; background-color: rgb(255, 26, 0);</canvasStyle>
   <canvasData>This is where the canvas html would go.</canvasData>
</root>
```

Comment: use `text/xml` OR `application/xml`.

Comment: Your server is not sending back the proper content type header.

Comment: So what exactly happens if you change the `dataType` argument to `"xml"`? Also, you should probably set an XML content-type response header in PHP, eg `header('Content-type: text/xml');`

Comment: Check the server response, it might not be what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your php code needs to send back the proper `Content-Type` header in order for jQuery (or some browsers?) to interpret it properly.

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml'); // or 'application/xml'
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be it.  I've added: header('Content-Type: text/xml'); to the top of the loadPage.php script and I still am not able to have  dataType="xml". When I set dataType="xml" the success function of the post call is not entered, (a debugger; there is not hit) so it looks like nothing happens when you execute the call. But when I change "xml" to "text" for dataType the success function is entered and data comes back.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I can't specify dataType as "xml" but it turns out that I don't have to in order to get jQuery to treat the downloaded file as XML and pull out the individual components for me, which is the goal here. If the file being loaded with ajax is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>  
   <bodyStyle>body style will go here;</bodyStyle>
   <canvasStyle>canvas style will go here</canvasStyle>
   <canvasData>canvas data will go here</canvasData>
</root>
```

then all  I need to pull out the three components of the file is:

```
$.post('loadPage.php', { siteName : siteName},function(xml) {
    var bodyStyle = $(xml).find("bodyStyle")[0].textContent;
    var canvasStyle = $(xml).find("canvasStyle")[0].textContent;
    var canvasData = $(xml).find("canvasData")[0].textContent;
});
```

where loadPage.php is

```
<?php
    $siteName = $_POST['siteName'];
    $fileName = "{$siteName}.xml";
    $fileSize = filesize($fileName);
    $filePath =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" . $fileName;
    $site_fp = fopen( $filePath, 'r');
    $data = fread($site_fp, $fileSize);
    echo $data;
?>
```